# Online Build Server TFS

Tags: azure, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm getting this list of errors*(C:\a\src\Allegro Web.nuget\nuget.targets (88): Unable to find version '2.0.1.0' of package...*) all of a sudden after doing a normal commit, please find below, however i didnt change any nuget specific configuration recently.

[image: Build Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an intermittent issue with Nuget which is fixed now.
More details on that here: https://twitter.com/nuget